# Exporting a database or container from Azure Cosmos DB to my local storage

Tags: export, azure-cosmosdb

`Azure Cosmos DB` has an option of `import` to the database from local storage however, it has no such option of `export`.

I want to know all possible methods of directly exporting the database or a container to my local storage (`json` files) ie. without involvement of any other storage such as `blob` storage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 options for your references:

1.Azure Cosmos DB Migration Tool, you could export cosmos db data into local json file,please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file).

2.Azure Data Factory,you could use copy activity to transfer data from [cosmos db source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db) into [local file system sinklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system).

Comment: Are these the only methods? This sure is helpful, I will check out the links. Why has Microsoft not provided  us with an export button just like an import one?

Comment: @aarohi-001 Yeah,these are simple and direct ways based on my knowledge. No option to export on the cosmos db portal UI indeed. You could submit feedback about this feature to improve cosmos db development from this link:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db

Comment: @aarohi-001 Especially the migration tool is the best option for you, i think.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing an error while using Data Migration tool. I've posted it as a question. Could you help me out? Here's the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047500/error-while-exporting-from-azure-cosmos-db-to-json-file-using-data-migration-too

Comment: @aarohi-001 Let me check.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple way to export data from *small* containers is via a SQL query.

Write a new SQL query against your container:

[image]

And use the default query to select all of your data

```
SELECT * FROM c
```

This will give you all of your data in a json format, and you can copy paste it to a local file.

Note that this is only a good option for relatively small data amounts. For larger amounts of data you should stick with the options suggested by @JayGong in the accepted answer.

Comment: No useful at all for exporting from cosmos db

Comment: @AntonioAvndañoDuran several other people found this useful, including myself. This is by far the easiest method for exporting small datasets as long as there's no built-in support for data export from CosmosDb. 
The other solutions are better suited for larger datasets, but are also more time consuming to set up.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your response, for example how export the records after the "SELECT * FROM c", that, by the way, is the default query in data explorer

Comment: Azure gives you the result of your query in a json format, as mentioned in my original answer. You'll see the result in a pane next to the query. You can simply copy paste this anywhere you like. There's no reason to overthink things like this if you're working with small amounts of data.