# Unable to import and export large data volume to or from cosmos DB container

Tags: azure, data-migration, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In my cosmos DB container there are 100,000 records, I am using migration [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-migrate-desktop-tool?tabs=azure-cli) to export all records in a JSON file but only approx. 30K records are getting exported each time I tried code below

```
{
"Source": "cosmos-nosql",
"SourceSettings": {   
"ConnectionString" :"AccountEndpoint=<URL>;AccountKey=<AccountKey>",
"Database": "DH-PRES-DB",
"Container":"Event",
"PartitionKeyPath": "/id",
"QueryText": "Select * from c"
  },
  "Sink": "json",
  "SinkSettings": {    
  "FilePath" : "C:\\Users\\us25\\Downloads\\dmtFile\\Event_test.json"
  }
}
```

Similarly, I tried for JSON import into cosmos container but I'm unable to import all records. Any idea what needs to be fixed here please, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to import and export large data volume to or from cosmos DB container

To export data from Azure Cosmos DB to local machine you can also use **`Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool`** which exports the data even if it is more than **30k**.

**Follow the below steps to export the data:**

- Data count in the Azure Cosmos DB Container:
  [image]
- Install `Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool`, click on `Sorce Information` and fill the Azure Cosmos DB details. In the Connection String add the database details at last of the connection string and verify the connection as shown below:
  [image]
- Now click on `Target Information` and select `Json` at **Export To** and select `Local file` as you want to store it in local machine and select the local path and click on `Prettify Json` as shown below:
  [image]
- Verify the `Connection String` and `Target` and click on **Import** as shown below:
  [image]
- Then the data will be successfully exported from Azure Cosmos DB to the local Json file as shown below:
  [image]

Comment: Thanks @Balaji for your answer but this UI based tool doesn't work for me so if you could try the same using latest tool I'm using and can help with the code change that needs to be done then I will be greatful.

Comment: To export large amount of data which is more than 30K it's better to choose either the above approach or by using Azure Data Factory. I tried from my end using Desktop data migration tool it is accepting only 30K at once. For more information, refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044209/exporting-a-database-or-container-from-azure-cosmos-db-to-my-local-storage).